# MySQL group by multiple columns on multiple tables only one result per group

Tags: mysql, select, group-by

I have three different tables and I need to count how many rows has a specific value (`COUNT(track)`) then group by `tracks.id` and sort by only one result per user (`tracks.uid`).

My three tables:

```
`users`
+--------+-------------------+
| `idu`  | `username`        | 
+--------+-------------------+
| 567    | 'TrainingPuppy'   | 
| 687    | 'BathroomMakeover'|
| 45     | 'PoshNachos'      | 
| 15     | 'SewingButtons'   | 
+--------+-------------------+

`views`
+--------+------+---------+
| `id`   | `by` | `track` |
+--------+------+---------+
| 1      | 5    | 55      | 
| 2      | 5    | 55      | 
| 3      | 67   | 55      | 
| 4      | 6    | 29      | 
| 5      | 125  | 2       | 
| 6      | 5    | 698     | 
| 7      | 5    | 698     | 
+--------+------+---------+

`tracks`
+--------+-------+-----------------------+---------------------+
| `id`   | `uid` | `title`               | `time`              |
+--------+-------+-----------------------+---------------------+
| 2      | 15    | 'Worf is in the air'  | 2016-02-11 22:57:35 |
| 29     | 567   | 'Stargold'            | 2016-08-11 22:57:28 |
| 55     | 567   | 'No love liers'       | 2016-10-11 22:57:51 | 
| 698    | 567   | 'Lofe'                | 2016-11-11 22:57:44 |
+--------+-------+-----------------------+---------------------+
```

So I tried:

```
SELECT `views`.`track`, `tracks`.*, `users`.*, COUNT(`track`) as `count` 
FROM `views`,`tracks`,`users` 
WHERE `views`.`track` = `tracks`.`id` 
    AND `tracks`.`uid` = `users`.`idu`  
GROUP BY `tracks`.`uid` 
ORDER BY `count` 
DESC LIMIT 0, 20
```

**RESULTS**

```
+--------+-------+---------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------+---------------------+
| `id`   | `uid` | `count` | `username`          | `track`  | `title`               | `time`              |
+--------+-------+---------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------+---------------------+
| 29     | 567   |  6      | 'TrainingPuppy'     | 29       | 'Stargold'            | 2016-10-11 22:57:51 | 
| 2      | 15    |  1      | 'SewingButtons'     | 2        | 'Worf is in the air'  | 2016-02-11 22:57:35 |
+--------+-------+---------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------+---------------------+
```

Instead I need to select only 1 track (the most counted in views table) of each user.
Something like below:

```
+--------+-------+---------+---------------------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
| `id`   | `uid` | `count` | `username`          | `track`  | `title`             | `time`              |
+--------+-------+---------+---------------------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
| 55     | 567   |  3      | 'TrainingPuppy'     | 55       | 'No love liers'     | 2016-10-11 22:57:51 | 
| 2      | 15    |  1      | 'SewingButtons'     | 2        | 'Worf is in the air'| 2016-02-11 22:57:35 |
+--------+-------+---------+---------------------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Improper use of `GROUP BY`; see the tag I added.

Comment: @RickJames Could you please explain?

Comment: See [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html)! Yet another reason why MySQL should not be used for serious work!

Comment: @NineCattoRules: ANSI std says all non-aggregate columns from the `select` list should show up in the `group by` clause and vice versa (ie, all columns in `group by` clause should show up as non-aggregates in the `select` list); failure to follow the ANSI std leaves you at the mercy of the RDBMS and how it chooses to process a non-ANSI `group by` ... usually leading to undesired results

Comment: @Vérace - a partial fix:  As of 5.7.5, `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` is enabled by default.

Comment: @NineCattoRules turn on `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`.  It won't solve your problem, but it will spit at you until you do solve it.

Comment: @RickJames Thanks but I have MySQL 5.6, and I'm using Amazon RDS.

Comment: @markp irrelevant to the question and the issue but the vice-versa ("all columns in group by clause should show up as non-aggregates in the select list") is not true. `SELECT a, min(d) FROM t GROUP BY a,b,c;` is perfectly valid.

Comment: @NineCattoRules - what is the full version number?  And is it Aurora?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ: lots of examples are `valid` based on individual RDBMSs; if you expect your example query to return a single row for `a` (given different values of `b/c`) then you're in for a surprise as some RDBMs will actually return multiple rows for `a, min(d)`

Comment: I would expect multiple rows with same values in `a` column, one for each (a,b,c) combination (and possibly different min(d) values). And that's what all serious DBMS would return. No surprises. Even MySQL will handle that query just right.

Comment: @RickJames MySQL version 5.6.27 and I don't have Aurora

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setup the tables and some sample data:

```
drop table if exists users;
drop table if exists views;
drop table if exists tracks;

create table users
(idu      int
,username varchar(30));

create table views
(id       int
,`by`     int
,track    int);

create table tracks
(id       int
,uid      int
,title    varchar(30)
,time     datetime);

insert into users values
(567,'TrainingPuppy'),
(687,'BathroomMakeover'),
( 45,'PoshNachos'),
( 15,'SewingButtons');

insert into views values
(1,  5, 55),
(2,  5, 55),
(3, 67, 55),
(4,  6, 29),
(5,125,  2),
(6,  5,698),
(7,  5,698);

insert into tracks values
(  2, 15,'Worf is in the air','2016-02-11 22:57:35'),
( 29,567,'Stargold'          ,'2016-08-11 22:57:28'),
( 55,567,'No love liers'     ,'2016-10-11 22:57:51'),
(698,567,'Lofe'              ,'2016-11-11 22:57:44');
```

Start with a (ANSI standard `group by`) query to obtain our counts:

```
select tracks.id,
       tracks.uid,
       count(*) as ucount,
       users.username,
       views.track,
       tracks.title,
       tracks.time

from   tracks
join   views
on     views.track = tracks.id

join   users
on     users.idu = tracks.uid

group by tracks.id,
         tracks.uid,
         users.username,
         views.track,
         tracks.title,
         tracks.time
```

We'll call the above 'user_counts', and create a query that generates a ranking over `username` ordered by `ucount desc`:

```
select id,
       uid,
       ucount,
       username,
       track,
       title,
       time,
       @user_rank := if(@current_username = username, @user_rank:=@user_rank+1, 1) as user_rank,
       @current_username := username

from   user_counts,

        -- initialize our variables
join   (select @user_rank := 0, @current_username := 'abcdefg') r

order by username, ucount desc
```

Then wrap this in our final `select`, making sure to only display those rows with a ranking of '1' ... pulling it all together into a single query we have:

```
select id,
       uid,
       ucount as 'count',
       username,
       track,
       title,
       time

from   (select id,
               uid,
               ucount,
               username,
               track,
               title,
               time,
               @user_rank        := if(@current_username = username, @user_rank:=@user_rank+1, 1) as user_rank,
               @current_username := username

        from   (select tracks.id,
                       tracks.uid,
                       count(*) as ucount,
                       users.username,
                       views.track,
                       tracks.title,
                       tracks.time

                from    tracks
                join    views
                on      views.track = tracks.id

                join    users
                on      users.idu = tracks.uid

                group by tracks.id,
                         tracks.uid,
                         users.username,
                         views.track,
                         tracks.title,
                         tracks.time) user_counts

                -- initialize our variables
        join   (select @user_rank := 0, @current_username := 'abcdefg') r

        order by username, ucount desc) dt

where   user_rank = 1

order by ucount desc, username
```

And the results:

```
id uid count username      track title              time
-- --- ----- ------------- ----- ------------------ -------------------
55 567     3 TrainingPuppy    55 No love liers      2016-10-11 22:57:51
 2  15     1 SewingButtons     2 Worf is in the air 2016-02-11 22:57:35
```

Some fiddles:

- [MySQL 5.6](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tP7PZtbdUvrfmPyjuxDoo/1)
- [MySQL 5.7](http://rextester.com/XJNC34508)
- [MariaDB 10.2](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=8aebb6d631786d91d7bbbd5def993c31)

---

NOTE: If a given `username` has the same max(count) for more than one track/title, this solution will only display one record; to display multiple records would require a tweak to ensure said records receive the same ranking (ie, `user_rank = 1`).

Comment: Thanks, this is brilliant...however I need to `DESC LIMIT 0, 20` the `ucount` since I'm using an Ajax call request system with infinite scroll down.

Comment: ok, so add your `limit 0,20` to the final query ... yes?

Comment: It's also very nice that I can get how many records needed of each artist just using something like  `user_rank < 3` (max 2 tracks of the same artist)